# How can I mock a provider when testing a config function in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I have a config function with this signature:

```
tmsNav = angular.module('tmsNav', ['tmsAuthSvc', 'tmsConfig', 'ui.router'])
tmsNav.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, statesConfig) {
    // uses the constant statesConfig to configure $stateProvider and $urlRouterProvider
});
```

Here is my describe block:

```
describe('tmsNav.config() >', function () {
    it('configures states correctly', function () {
        module('tmsConfig', function ($provide) {
            $provide.constant('statesConfig', states1);
            $provide.factory('$state', function () {
                return {
                    state: function () {
                        console.log('state()!!!');
                    }
                };
            });
        });
        module('tmsNav');
        inject(function ($state) {
            expect($state.get().length).toBe(4);
        });
    });
});
```

The constant is successfully overwritten, but $stateProvider isn't.  I've tried using `$provide.factory('$state', ...)`, `$provide.constant('$stateProvider', ...)`, `$provide.value('$state', ...)`, etc...  Nothing has worked.

I need to mock $stateProvider because once it's configured it retains that configuration going into the next test.  So when I run subsequent tests I get errors about duplicate configuration values when I shouldn't.

Answer (score 2):

The answer lies in the module() statements.  I was trying to overwrite $stateProvider on the wrong module.

```
module('tmsConfig', function ($provide) {
    $provide.constant('statesConfig', states1);
});
module('ui.router', function ($provide) {
    $provide.provider('$state', function () {
        this.state = function () {
            console.log('state()!!!');
        };
        this.$get = function () {
            return {
                get: function () {
                    return [];
                }
            };
        };
    });
});
module('tmsNav');
```

This edit causes the test to pass if I reduce the length expectation to zero.  That's not really the test I want anyway so I'll write a more robust mock with spies and such now that the provider issue is resolved.

Comment: I spent a long time trying to figure this out only to solve it myself three minutes after posting the question.  Doh!

Comment: don't worry it happens quite often :)